# Makefile - Help me in getting the error removed

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I am building a program from a single `main.c` file.

Errors appear when using `make`

Note - I have 64 bit library files in a folder lib.

Earlier 32 bit Linux platform I was working on.
Now it's 64 bit Linux version.

```
CC = gcc 
INCLUDES = -I../include 
LIBDIRS = -L../lib 
LIBFILES = \. -lCAPI32 -lNCCOM  -lNCMOCHA -lMOCHA -lMELCFG -lhiredis -lMELWIN
LIBS = $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBFILES) 
DEFINES = -D_LINUX 
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -pthread -g -m32

all: 
    $(CC). $(CFLAGS) main.c $(LIBS)-ldl 
    chmod +X a.out

run: all (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib/;. \ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;\ .a.out)

Clean:
    rm -f a.out
```

Error are:

```
Skipping incompatible ../lib//libNCAP32.so when searching for -lNCAP32
Cannot find -lNCAP32
```

a lot of time

Comment: Please add the text of the makefile and the errors generated to your question.

Comment: No pictures please. Just cut and paste from your terminal.

Comment: Sorry I am new for this platform so it happened. I will just type in here a code.

Comment: Please add the missing information to the question. Copy&paste the real code from makefile, don't retype it. You can use the `edit` button below your question to add more details.

Comment: Make file code : 1) CC = gcc.      2) INCLUDES = -I../include.   3) LIBDIRS = -L../lib    4) LIBFILES = \.  -lCAPI32.\  -lNCCOM \ -lNCMOCHA\ -lMOCHA\ -lMELCFG\ -lhiredis\ -lMELWIN.                                                        LIBS = $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBFILES)             DEFINES = -D_LINUX                              CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -pthread -g -m32.                                      all: $(CC). $(CFLAGS) main.c $(LIBS)-ldl.                                    Chmod +X  a.out

Comment: run: all              (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib/;. \ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;\ .a.out).                     Clean:.    rm -f a.out.

Comment: Please add this to the question, not in comments.

Comment: @ShridharNayak Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73077878/edit) facility to update your question.  Do *not* put code in the comments.

Comment: I am trying but unable to.. as I am new for this platform

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the `-m32` option passed to `gcc` asking it to generate 32bits code.

I guess that the installed libraries are 64bits flavored

Just remove the `-m32` from `CFLAGS`

Comment: I tried with that.. and the only error which I am getting now is /usr/bin/ld: cannot find  -lhiredis

Comment: is `hiredis` library present on your system ?

Comment: When I have received a 64 bit library files I was not having -lhiredis . But I have copied the 32 bit Linux version lhiredis in 64 bit Linux version. May be that is causing the error. But from where I can get lhiredis in 64 bit version.

Comment: A 32 bit library won't work in a 64 bits program. Same for the opposite.

Comment: I guess you can ask the guy who gives you the other library? Or you can try to compile by yourself : https://github.com/redis/hiredis

Comment: Thank you so much. I will just ask once. If any further queries will revert back to you.